# How to fix : "RuntimeError: Too early to create image" error

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageSequence
import time

def play_gif():
    global img
    img = Image.open("document2.gif")
    lbl = Label(root)
    lbl.place(x=150,y=50)

    for img in ImageSequence.Iterator(img):

        img = img.resize((300,300))
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        lbl.config(image = img)

        root.update()
        time.sleep(0.04)
    root.after(0,play_gif)

  
root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x400")
#root.configure(bg="white")
play_gif()

root.mainloop()
```

When I close the tkinter window, I am getting the above error, can somebody please help me fix it ?

I want to run gif in ttkinter window as a loading screen

Comment: Why are you doing `root.after(0,play_gif)`? Wouldn't it go into an infinite recursion? Moreover, I don't think the window will open as `root.mainloop()` never gets executed.

Comment: @SriramSrinivasan `root.mainloop()` will get executed as the infinite recursion only starts once the window opens. Also, I think the infinite recursion is on purpose, so that the `gif` plays over and over again

Comment: @Lecdi My bad. In many situations, I have seen that the window opens and immediately closes if `mainloop` is not executed because of the absence of an event loop. But in this case, as the gif is being played indefinitely, there is no need for events to keep the window open. That's an interesting point. Thanks for pointing out my misconception.

Comment: @Lecdi Actually, it turns out that if `play_gif` is used instead of `root.after(0,play_gif)`, the window opens and then immediately closes. When the latter is used, `play_gif` is executed once, reaches the end of the function, sees `.after(0, ...)`, executes `.mainloop()` and then comes back and recursively continues with `play_gif`. Using `.after` is a clever hack. So, I think my original understanding of using `.mainloop` was actually correct.